# BufferedReader System.in IOException

Tags: java

Хочу разобраться, столкнулся с очень интересной проблемой.
Это магия работы ридера System.in или что-то другое?

Есть некий класс, внутри метода которого создается ридер и цикл. Внутри цикла у пользователя спрашиваются какие-то данные и в зависимости от этих данных вызывается тот или иной метод у другого класса.

```
void someMethod() {
     boolean myBoolean = false;
     AppManager appManager = new AppManager();
     Bufferedreader consolerReader = new BufferedReader(new InputstreamReader(System.in));

     while (!myBoolean) {
           System.out.println(".......?");
           String userAnswer = consoleReader.readLine();
           if (userAnswer.equals("Value")) {
               appManager.method();
           }
     }
}
```

Внутри метода другого класса создается еще один ридер.

```
void anotherMethod() {
    Bufferedreader consolerReader = new BufferedReader(new InputstreamReader(System.in));
    do something...
    consoleReader.close();
}
```

Если этот ридер закрыть, то закрывается и первый ридер. Если не закрывать - то все будет работать.
Вопрос: при создании еще одного идентичного ридера System.in второй ридер получает ссылку на первый? Получается что так. Но почему это происходит? Почему если я в первом методе создам любой другой объект и во втором методе такой же объект - это будут разные объекты в памяти? Даже если сделать 2 ридера, но не System.in, а, к примеру, разных файлов - все должно работать(я полагаю).

Comment: Вы используете общий `System.in` и закрывая `consolerReader` закрывается и сам `System.in`. Поэтому при следующей попытки чтения из закрытого `System.in` вылетает исключение.